# How do I automate Jenkins SSH credentials creation/assigning to nodes?

Tags: ssh, jenkins, automation, credentials, slave

I am writing an *automated Jenkins machine creation* script, and I have encountered a problem with SSH credentials, namely:

In Jenkins there is a file called `credentials.xml` (in `/var/lib/jenkins`) which stored credentials for the nodes. Mine looks like so:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider plugin="credentials@1.18">
  <domainCredentialsMap class="hudson.util.CopyOnWriteMap$Hash">
    <entry>
      <com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain>
        <specifications/>
      </com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain>
      <java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList>
        <com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>
          <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
          <id>8743cc14-bc2c-44a6-b6bb-c121bef4ae2d</id>
          <description>root_with_secret</description>
          <username>root</username>
          <password>2Xd4i7+8tjVXg2RHP6ggl/ZtWJp177ajXNajJxsj80o=</password>
        </com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>
      </java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList>
    </entry>
  </domainCredentialsMap>
```

There is (are) also nodes (slaves) configuration file(s) (stored in `/var/lib/jenkins/nodes/HOSTNAME/config.xml` for each slave) which look(s) like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<slave>
  <name>HOSTNAME_OF_MY_SECRET_MACHINE</name>
  <description>HOSTNAME_OF_MY_SECRET_MACHINE</description>
  <remoteFS>/root</remoteFS>
  <numExecutors>1</numExecutors>
  <mode>NORMAL</mode>
  <retentionStrategy class="hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy$Always"/>
  <launcher class="hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher" plugin="ssh-slaves@1.9">
    <host>10.0.10.1</host>
    <port>22</port>
    <credentialsId>8743cc14-bc2c-44a6-b6bb-c121bef4ae2d</credentialsId>
    <maxNumRetries>0</maxNumRetries>
    <retryWaitTime>0</retryWaitTime>
  </launcher>
  <label></label>
  <nodeProperties/>
  <userId>anonymous</userId>
</slave>
```

The problem is that after I create the jenkins machine, copy `credentials.xml` and `config.xml`s for each slave then the credentials wouldn't work. I get

```
[07/26/15 16:00:39] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 10.0.10.1:22.
ERROR: Failed to authenticate as root. Wrong password. (credentialId:8743cc14-bc2c-44a6-b6bb-c121bef4ae2d/method:password)
[07/26/15 16:00:41] [SSH] Authentication failed.
hudson.AbortException: Authentication failed.
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1178)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:701)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:696)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[07/26/15 16:00:41] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[07/26/15 16:00:41] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

To solve this issue I can go to *Jenkins* -> *Credentials* -> and then update the credential with the same password that I would use anyway and it will work.

So the question is whether Jenkins uses kind of salting/hashing per installation so that the `credentials.xml` will not work if copied to a new machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I have managed to solve this with (I believe) a workaround-ish solution, namely:

To store a password in plain text in `credentials.xml`, copy it over to the Jenkins machine after installing and starting the service. Then Jenkins will encrypt it with its new secret (or whatever it uses for that purpose) and it will work :)

**EDIT**

A second option is to install Jenkins, start it, and then copy the `credentials.xml` with encrypted passwords together with `secrets` directory and `secret.xml` from previous installation. This will copy both encryption master key and the encrypted credentials that have been created using this master key.

Comment: Thanks, storing plaintext in credentials.xml indeed works great! It is worth noting that it *doesn't* work to store them plaintext in the xml configuration of a job itself (such as via a FolderCredentialsProvider), so if you were doing that, you'll need to convert to using and referencing system credentials that get persisted to credentials.xml.